# I do not want to send auto order email in magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, ce-1.9.1.1

Is there any way to stop magento order email. I do not want to send email automatically I'll send order email manually by admin *Sales -> Orders -> Send email*.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Admin->System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Order**

Set Enabled to No

[image]