# Stop sending all emails

Tags: email, ce-1.9.1.0, order-email

Don't ask why but my client doesn't want all order emails being send. Is there an easy way to stop this? He wants to send these mails himself. So all automatic outgoing emails (order) needs to be stopped. When there is a new order don't send any email and also on the other order mails after that (status/updates etc).

Comment: Which Magento Version?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I'm on 1.9.1.0

Comment: Just seeing these settings; I think when setting off (SALES > EMAILS FOR SALES) will also not send email to the store owner when there is a new order? Only the client who orders don't need to get any emails

Comment: Oh, btw: if you really want to disable ALL emails to customers, there's a setting in System>Configuration>Admin for this

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple way for your version is to install a module like `Aoe_Scheduler` which allows you to disable specific cron tasks, and disable core_email_queue_send. As far as I know, in 1.9.1.0 the only emails that use this cron task are order confirmations. You should check first to be sure, though.

Comment: Istalled the module. Just to mention; I use this module to send because Magento didn't work out of the box for sending emails: http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/

Comment: Should work with it, afaik it only changes the way mails are sent, not then "when"

Comment: I just did a test order but got email. I disabled core_email_queue_send_all but it looks like its ignoring it.

Comment: Hm, ok; maybe it's not working because of the module then. I think you will then have to write a custom module and either listen to an event, or rewrite the order model

Comment: I saw this post in the sidebar and think this will work. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109683/i-do-not-want-to-send-auto-order-email-in-magento-1-9-1-1?rq=1
But as I posted before I'm not sure the site owner gets email when there is a new order. Testing 123

Comment: Hmm, now the site owner also doesn't get any email when there is a new order..

Comment: Ok well I disabled all except the new order one which seems to satify my client. Thanks for your help simon. I think your solution didn't work because I haven't set any cronjobs. Just use the smtppro module to send email.

Comment: Ok, no problem; yes, normally since 1.9 Magento uses Cron to send mails (which can be seen in numerous wondering questions all around here ;) ). Maybe SMTPPro overrides this behaviour. Glad you got it working for you!